# javascript function not recognized inside bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a Bootstrap button dropdown list, where each element in the list calls a function and pass its id into it.  My js functions are defined in an object called Search, which is instantiated on page load.  Here's my setup.

```
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn" role="group">
                        <button type="button" id='filelist' class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" onclick='search.print()'>
                            List Of <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id='filelist_ul' role="menu" >
                          <li><a id='var1' onclick='search.print(var1)'>Var1</a></li>
                          <li><a id='var2' onclick='search.print(var2)'>Var2</a></li>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>  
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='uploadtype_text' readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name='filelist'>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                    <div class='input-group-btn'>
                        <input type="submit" name="uploadfile_form" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger"/>
                        <button type='button' name='clear' class='btn btn-success' onclick='search.clearResults()'>Clear</button>
                    </div>   
                </div>
```

`search.print()` gets called correctly when I attach it to the main `"List Of"` button, however, when I click any of the li elements, I'm getting the error

```
search.print is not a function
```

I've gotten this working before in other cases, but for some reason this is breaking, and I can't figure it out.  I seems like a syntax error or something I'm missing.  The variable search doesn't look like it's getting overridden either.  I don't get it.

Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rnxx4rnc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind `search` to the `window` object.

```
$(function() {
  window.search = new Search();
});
```

Comment: Did you call the correct object in the view `onclick="window.search.print(var2)"`?

Comment: So that worked but I'm not 100% sure this is the solution I need.  I've never had to do bind my other objects to the window, and they've worked.  Plus I'm looking for an explanation of why search.print() works when bound to the onclick of the button, but becomes undefined when bound on the li elements.